# Java mobile for datalogic elf

Tags: java, mobile, barcode-scanner, windows-mobile-6.5

I've been given the opportunity to develop an application to collect data including scanning and generating bar codes on a Datalogic ELF. The os is windows mobile 6.5, and the SDK supports java, however there seems to be very little in the way of examples or help etc. I would be grateful for any advice, links, tutorials for Java development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datalogic does not offer there SDK for JAVA only. Did you download and install there SDK from http://www.datalogic.com/eng/support-services/automatic-data-capture/downloads/software-utilities-sw-2.html?search_cat=27&search_prod=144.

The site states SDK for C++/.Net/JAVA and I assume it is coming with usage examples.

Further on you need a JVM runtime installed on the device. Does it really come with a JVM pre-installed? Normally you have to buy and install CrEme or J9 JVM for handheld devices running WEH6.5.

I would go with .NET (WEH65 comes with CF 3.5) or C++ and not install an additional Runtime, except for you are really in the need to do it in JAVA. Mostly the JAVA support of handheld SDKs is very limitted.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have installed the SDK from Datalogic. I was looking for an alternative to C#, due to the whole what version of windows! visual studio I would need etc. as the SDK included Java I thought I'd look inti it.

Comment: Although VS2005 or VS2008 is needed (no newer version supports WEH65 development!), the setup for WEH development is much easier then setting up Eclipse or NetBeans for windows mobile development. VS offers all in one ready-to-use setup (after install of WEH 6.5 DTK) but for eclipse/netbeans you have to find all the puzzle pieces (I never really got it to work with remote launching and debugging to work).